# How to listen on a physical device event in a C# web service using COM

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, events, com

I have a web service that needs to wait on a physical device response to do some processing and return the results to the caller. The DLLs that control the physical device use COM.

The code is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public DeviceResponse SendDeviceRequest(int deviceId)
    {
        DeviceObject device = new DeviceObject();

        AutoResetEvent resetEvent= new AutoResetEvent(false);
        EventHandler handler = new EventHandler (Device,resetEvent);

        handler.subscribeEvent(); 

        device.requestResponse(deviceId);

        resetEvent.WaitOne(); //wait until device has fired the response event

        //Do processing with device response
    }
```

The following is the EventHandler class:

```
public class EventHandler
{
    DeviceObject device;
    AutoResetEvent resetEvent;

    public EventHandler (DeviceObject deviceObject,AutoResetEvent are)
    {
        device= deviceObject;
        resetEvent = are;
    }

    public void subscribeEvent()
    {
        device.OnDeviceResponse += new OnDeviceResponseEventHandler(OnResponse);
    }

    public void OnResponse(CustomParams params) 
    {
        //handle device response
        resetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the `OnResponse` method is never executed and the method keeps waiting for `resetEvent.Set()`. However, if I implement the EventHandler using WindowsForms, the event is handled correctly, even without using the `AutoResetEvents` object. I strongly suspect this happens due to disruption of communication between the COM threads and the main thread.

The questions are then: How can I have the COM threads and the main thread communicate so that I can listen to the device event triggered in the COM DLL's? Do I have to implement the thread apartment handling procedures myself (so that it works like it does in a Windows Forms application), or is there already a mechanism provided by .NET to achieve this?

Comment: First and most obvious question that comes to my mind: are you certain that the device's `requestResponse` method is actually asynchronous?

Comment: What does `device.requestResponse(deviceId)` do, and are you sure it's triggering `OnDeviceResponse`?

Comment: @Alden device.requestResponse(deviceId) sends a request to thedevice with the given id to execute an operation. After that control is given to the device. The device fires the OnDeviceResponse event when it has finished processing the request issued by the device.requestResponse(deviceId) method.

Comment: @DavidH the requestResponse method is executed synchronously, but I am not sure on how to handle the asynchronous event from the device or why the same implementation works in a windows form application. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
    handler.subscribeEvent(); 

    device.requestResponse(deviceId);

    resetEvent.WaitOne();//wait until device has fired the response event
    //Do processing with device response
```

With:

```
    handler.subscribeEvent(); 

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        device.requestResponse(deviceId);
    });
    thread.Start();

    resetEvent.WaitOne();//wait until device has fired the response event

    //Do processing with device response
```

Comment: After the change the result was the same. Somehow the EventHandler is not entering th OnResponse method when the device fires the event.

Comment: Logically, one can only assume that the device never raises the event. How odd.

Comment: Since I know this works if I implement it using a Windows Forms application and the only difference with my code is that I'm not using the STAThread attribute I guess that could be the reason. The reason I didn't use this before was because I was told the dlls for the device didn't use COM, but I believe they do. I will confirm this tomorrow and let you know what happens.

Comment: I tested the mentioned change and it didn't work. After further reading the problem seems to come from the communication with the COM dlls that control the physical device. I will edit the OP to reflect this.

Comment: I was finally able to talk to the provider of the libraries that fire the events and it turned out that they didn't add support for multithreaded apartment to the COM libraries I am using. Subscribing to the events like @DavidHaney suggested does work if using a single thread.